# JQuery select dropdowns in a div

Tags: jquery

How do I select the ID of a dropdownlist that has been changed in a div?.

i.e a

```
<div class="a">
    <select name="ddl1748" id="ddl748">
        <option value="Change">Change</option>
    </select>
    <select name="ddl1749" id="ddl749">
        <option value="Change">Change1</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I have a lot of dropdown boxes in the div .

Comment: Can you show the markup want want to do this against?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to get the IDs of those select boxes, which values have been changed by the user. If so, you can listen for the `change` event:

```
var changed = [];

$('div.a').delegate('select', 'change', function() {
    changed.push(this.id);
});
```

[`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) binds only **one** event handler to the parent `div`. Of course, if a select box is changed more then once, you have to check beforehand, whether the ID is already contained in the array or not. Or you could use an object to store the IDs, e.g.:

```
var changed = {};

$('div.a').delegate('select', 'change', function() {
    changed[this.id] = 1;
});
```

Then you would have to iterate over the properties of that object.

Comment: I have a command that changes all the dropdown items default value. After that If I change the Dropdown it does not run the delegate , any reasons.